# Text centering cross-browser issue

Tags: css, cross-browser, positioning

I don't see what would control text to be offset on different computers, as seen below. One is centered within the blue area correctly, the other seems offset somehow.  It's happening in a text field and a button. Live site: http://www.muuzik.me:8000

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have some [invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.muuzik.me%3A8000%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  You also have a `<script>` outside of the `<html></html>` tags and this is invalid structure.  Nothing should be outside of the `html` tags with the exception of the `doctype` at the top, which in your case, is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The key is in adjusting the padding around that element. Currently there is 18px of padding on the top and 4px of padding on the bottom. That's not balanced, so the text won't be centered vertically. To get it centered horizontally, make sure that the left and right padding are the same; to get it centered vertically, make sure that the top and bottom padding are the same.

It probably helps things that you can use a shorthand declaration to create this effect:
`padding: 10px 20px;` will set the top & bottom to 10px and the left & right to 20px.

Comment: but the problem is it's not just a case of getting padding right or not, different browsers are centering/not centering the text, regardless of what padding is set

Comment: If the padding is too small, it might be ignored in some browsers. What browsers are you having trouble with after you set the padding to be equal?

Comment: this computer (one that's not centering the text) is using chromium 19.0.1084.46, but two other chrome computers center it.

Comment: I'm just wondering what css property allows you to center text within that blue area (i.e. not padding)

Comment: I can't replicate what you're seeing in chrome, but I can in IE. The issue there isn't that the padding isn't working: it's that the background isn't being extended to fill everything that the padding extends. And I do not believe there is a css property that will center things without the padding being set correctly.

Comment: @ChrisBolton, until you fix [your invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.muuzik.me%3A8000%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), rendering across browsers is doomed to be inconsistent.

Comment: @JeffreyBlake hm this is interesting.. it's actually not flush with the top, it's being offset a bit somehow (I think by 15px): http://ompldr.org/vZHMwOA

Comment: also not sure I follow about the background and how it relates

Comment: The top padding is causing that offset. That's exactly what I'm trying to tell you. Change the padding and you will change the vertical position. My experiment leads me to think that the ideal vertical padding (e.g. both top and bottom) for cross-browser vertical centering will be 8px. So either set `padding-top:8px;` and `padding-bottom:8px` OR set `padding:8px 20px;`

Comment: here is a screenshot with the padding you've specified: http://ompldr.org/vZHMwYg

Comment: as you can see.. the padding is irrelevant.

Comment: Does it look exactly the same if you set it to `padding:80px 20px;`? You might have to adjust the numbers to find the sweet spot. In every browser I can test, my suggestion fixes the issue on the page you're showing me. That's the best I can do.

Comment: http://ompldr.org/vZHMwYw
http://ompldr.org/vZHMwZA

those are actually the /exact/ same browser and css, /all/ I did was type an extra letter after messing with the height

Answer (score 1):

I think that is the padding settings. See the green areas? Those are the paddings. Your curren t padding is

```
 padding-top:14px; 
 padding-right:18px 
 padding-bottoem:4px;
 padding-left:18px;
```

That is why the text is not presented in center;
You can try to set the padding to

```
 padding: 12px;
```

I tried this, it works for me on Chrome and Firefox

Comment: the padding is irrelevant, the text is offset no matter what the padding is, the problem isn't in the green it's in the blue: http://ompldr.org/vZHMwOA

Answer (score 0):

You should show the whole CSS, but did you try to set `text-align: center;` and `line-height: 46px`to the button?

Comment: didn't seem to help, also added the site to the OP so you can see the css